# PHP: inline get element from associative array returned by a function

Tags: php, element, associative-array

I have a PHP function returning an associative array and I would like to get an element from it. Normally, I first create array from function and then I get element

```
$associative_array = someFunction();
$element = $associative_array['key'];
```

Is it possible to get element directly inline? (I can't change function to return the element).
Something like this (which fails due to syntax error, but it's just to show the idea):

```
$element = someFunction()['key'];
```

Comment: `$element = someFunction()['key'];` is perfectly valid syntax with the right version of PHP, e.g. PHP 5.4 and above, which means in all officially __supported__ versions of PHP. It's called `array dereferencing`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm using ver. 5.3.16, that's why I see the error. Do you know if there is a solution compatible with old versions?

Comment: The solution compatible with old versions is to do what you're doing already, saving the result of someFunction() to a variable, then accessing the keyed value from that variable.... the better solution is to upgrade to 5.4, which itself is now only in security patch mode

Comment: Upgrade to PHP 5.4! PHP 5.3 is old is was released 30 Jun 2009...

Comment: I'll upgrade to 5.4 ASAP. Thanks for hints!